# trying to track down source of a bootstrap hover effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My manager has asked me to copy the Bootstrap implementation for header notifications.  I've copied down the html and I've mapped the css. The one remaining piece is that I'm not sure where the hover effect for the close button is coming from.  I inspected the html and used Chrome dev tools. Any idea where the hover effect for the close button is coming and how I can bring down the effect into my local implementation?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts

Comment: Search for `.close` inside the CSS file: [dist/css/bootstrap.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) and you'll see it at line #5851.

Comment: Do you mean the little 'X' off to the right?

Comment: It is on the `.close` class though - in Chrome you can check the filter :hov and this will toggle the hover state so you can see the hover styles in effect.

Comment: @vanburen - if you post your comment as an answer then I'll mark it as an answer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover rules for the `.close` class are located on line #5851 of the **bootstrap.css** file:

**Alert Hover CSS** See line #5851 of [dist/css/bootstrap.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

```
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

**Working Example:** *Hover/Focus Color and opacity changed.*

```css
button.close:hover,
button.close:focus {
  color: #f00;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```